# What is Worf's shrine?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9, klingon, worf

In Deep Space Nine Season 6, Episode 16 "Change of Heart" roughly 3 minutes into the episode, Jadzia and Worf are getting ready for bed and talking business/work. Worf lights candles and opens a small box-like shrine, not unlike Hindu or Catholic (Mary) boxes. Jadzia turns her mirror and she see Worf praying or meditating to the figure in the altar and stops mid sentence.

[image]

Honestly, at first I thought Worf had a mirror and Jadzia saw someone in the room and only after going back did I see Worf had opened the doors on the box.

**What is the shrine and what is it's importance to Worf and other Klingons?**

---

To clarify: I know it's a shrine, and I suspected who was in it. Answering with "It's a Shrine to [blank]" is not an answer. I am looking for focused details about Worf's and the Klingon's beliefs that relate to this shrine.

Comment: I've edited the question back into its original format. It's not appropriate to change the question in an attempt to invalidate an existing answer.

Comment: @Valorum Everyone but you agreed my edit reflected the actual original meaning of the question as it was from the beginning. Its not appropriate to reject clarifications that disagree with your earlier answers misunderstanding.

Comment: I disagree. You've edited in a clarification that's specifically intended to reject my answer to your question.

Comment: @Valorum Just read the original quotation. It calls it a shrine and the bolded question asks "what is it's importance to Worf and other Klingons" its RIGHT THERE in the original

Comment: @Valorum It is not specific to your answer. It is specific to ANY answer that only tell was the shrine is simplistically. If it applies to yours, that's not my fault

Comment: @Valorum, Joshua: if you have a dispute about this question, **take it to meta.** Any more edits and I'll lock the post.

Comment: @Randal'Thor I didn't edit, I restored my one and only edit from months ago. There's nothing to dispute, I simply drew attention to any future answerers that the question in bold was more than just "what is X". Feel free to clear up these comments. I don't know why this had become an issue after so long.

Answer (score 4):

The [script](http://ds9.trekcore.com/media/scripts/616.txt) describes it as a small shrine devoted to [Kahless](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Kahless_the_Unforgettable), a mytho-historical figure who (supposedly) founded the Klingon Empire and codified the rules of honour.

Worf would frequently quote his teachings and at one point, he traveled to the Temple of Boreth (in [TNG: Rightful Heir](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Rightful_Heir_(episode))) to refresh his belief in Klingon values.

> **INT. WORF & DAX'S QUARTERS - BEDROOM**
>
> Later that same evening, Worf and Dax are getting ready for bed.
>
> Worf is coming out of the bathroom, dressed in his    night clothes and
>   his hair loose and out of the     ponytail. Dax is also dressed for bed
>   and is brushing   out her hair in front of a vanity. **Worf moves to a 
>     small Kahless shrine and begins to light one or two     candles.**

Comment: This does tell me "what" it was. 1) a shrine (I had that) and 2) that the figure is Kahless (I suspected but had no source). However, you don't really tell me in any way what this shrine is to Worf and to Klingons. What's its importance? The main point of that episode is how Worf's heart couldn't abandon Jadzia just like Kahless and his wife's heart were too strong for the gods and so they killed the gods. And yet here is Worf praying to Kahless as if Kahless is a god? Your answer is really the bare minimum as it is. Was hoping for "what is this" qualitatively, not just "a Shrine to Kahless".

Comment: @Valorum I'm not asking anything new. *"What is this and what is it's importance to Worf and other Klingons?"* I already know it's a shrine and I didn't simply ask who was in it. I asked what it meant **to Worf**. That's been the question the whole time.